# VS code shortcuts to increase or decrease width of terminal window

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are shortcuts to decrease or increase editor panel width, so there must be ones for doing the same to the terminal

Comment: I don't think there is any way to change the terminal panel width.  It is just full width to the Activity Bar/Explorer view.

Answer (score 2):

Just in VS code go to Keyboard shortcuts and find "Resize Terminal Down/Up/Left/Right" and make custom keybinding as you like. In my case there were no default values.

Comment: To clarify, the resize **left** and **right** commands work on split terminals only, not on the terminal view itself.   It is unclear what exactly the OP was referring to.